# Find recently added entity with relation condition

Tags: javascript, sql, typeorm

I am struggling on how to make a join of pageContents and select only the latest one. I've got an error "zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"" on this query. Where is the problem?

```
return this.createQueryBuilder('page')
    .leftJoin(
      qb =>
          qb.from(PageContent, 'PageContent')
              .select('MAX(PageContent."createdAt")', 'created_at')
              .addSelect('PageContent."pageId"', 'page_id')
              .groupBy('"page_id"'),
      '"last_version"',
      '"last_version"."page_id" = page.id'
  )
  .leftJoinAndSelect('page.pageContents', '"PageContent"', '"PageContent."createdAt" = "last_version"."created_at"')
  .where('page.id = :id', { id: id })
  .getOne();
```

Comment: i've fixed it. the right query is:
return this.createQueryBuilder('page')
      .leftJoin(
        qb =>
          qb.from(PageContent, 'content')
            .select('MAX("content"."createdAt")', 'created_at')
            .addSelect('"content"."pageId"', 'page_id')
            .groupBy('"page_id"'),
        'last_version',
        '"last_version"."page_id" = page.id'
      )
      .leftJoinAndSelect('page.pageContents', 'pageContents', '"pageContents"."createdAt" = "last_version"."created_at"')
      .where('page.id = :id', { id: id })
      .getOne();

Comment: you could answer your own question (instead of posting it as a comment). will help others with the same problems, and you can earn reps.